# Distance metrics for probability distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I know there are several metrics out there for quantifying the difference between probability distributions. The KL-divergence is the most common but other examples include the Wasserstein metric and the Cramer metric. One thing I have not seen is something resembling an $L^p$ norm between distributions. What I mean is this:
$$
d(P,Q) = \left[ \int_{-\infty}^\infty  | P(x) - Q(x) |^p dx \right]^{1/p},
$$
where $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$ are probability distribution functions defined on the same domain (i.e. $[-\infty, +\infty]$). This is very similar to the Cramer distance but is defined in terms of the pdf instead of the cdf. Do people know of any reason why this would not work as a distance metric for probability distributions?

Comment: One possible reason is that every distribution has a cdf, but not every distribution has a pdf.

Answer (score -1):

Actually, I think this definition may be problematic if, for instance, either $P(x)$ or $Q(x)$ were delta distributions and $p > 1$. As a simple example, suppose $P(x) = \delta(x)$ and $Q(x) = \delta(x-1)$, and consider $p=2$; then the integral expands to
$$
\int \left[ \delta(x)\delta(x) - 2 \delta(x)\delta(x-1) + \delta(x-1)\delta(x-1) \right] = 2\, \delta(0).
$$

Taking the root of a delta-distribution seems ill-defined. But even if we didn't take the root, this result tells us nothing about how far apart the two deltas are, i.e. it'd give the same result whether $Q(x) = \delta(x-1)$ or $Q(x) = \delta(x-100)$.